# How to find the origin figure of an axes object in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Given an `axes` instance, is it possible to know to which `figure` the instance belongs?  For example, assume that I have a reference to an axes object, `ax`, and I want to have access to the figure that the axes belong to.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

_, ax = plt.subplots()
fig = ?
fig.set_tight_layout()
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.get_figure.html#matplotlib.axis.Axis.get_figure

Comment: What is unclear about this question?

Answer (score 2):

The `matplotlib.axes.Axes` object has [`get_figure()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_figure.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_figure) method that returns parent figure.

Comment: When I define `fig = plt.figure()` and then `ax = plt.axes()`, why does `fig is ax.get_figure()` return `False`?